# Display Ajax response in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm calling a PHP file, and it's returning the response when I view it in Firebug. However, it's not displaying on my page. I'm not sure if the success is actually firing, because I can't even run an alert, but it is working because the PHP code is firing and returning what it's supposed to.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://www.example.com',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: "text/html",
        crossDomain:'true',
        success: function (data) {
            $(".result").html(data);
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: You seem to be sticking params on your ajax request that don't belong. For example, why are you using contentType: "text/html" if you aren't sending text/html to the server? Why are you using .html() to insert possibly a javascript object or javascript array to the content of a div? My guess is you are making a cross-domain request to retrieve text/html which isn't allowed due to the same origin policy, so you started adding in parameters to try to force it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the ajax call on load or document ready.  The div may not exist at the time of response (page is interpreted top down).

Comment: well, the ajax request doesn't have to wait for onload to be executed, but he does need to wait until after the dom is ready to act upon it's success.

Comment: Yes, the Ajax request will fire, but it may not have anywhere to write the response.

Comment: `var req = $.ajax(...); $(function(){ req.done(dostuff) });` for example would be one way of getting the content as fast as possible, while still waiting for the dom to be ready to act upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little lesson about what your are doing.

When working with any form of Ajax (or JavaScript in general), it is usually imperative to have your console open. You will be able to see your request, your response, and whole other useful information.

I usually work with Firefox and Chrome from time to time.

You can open your console by right clicking on the page anywhere and inspect an element with Firebug (on Firefox).

And inspect element in Chrome.

Once you see the Ajax call, click the <kbd>+</kbd> and see its content.

You should see something like:

> Headers Post Response JSON Cookies or something alike.

I hope that helps.